# Adding or subtracting to MySql based on user input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-update

The concept seems simple but I'm having trouble. I have a PHP form where users input numbers, a jQuery performs real-time calculations based on numbers inputted and numbers in the database, then the user can decide to submit the form-- after which their input is sent to the database (i.e. like a transaction). The numbers submitted is THEN appended to the existing numbers which will affect the real-time calculations the next time.

The problem is that every time the user hits "update," even if their input has not changed the SQL query appends the numbers. Furthermore, I can't seem to figure out how to make it add OR subtract. I want it to add or subtract or do nothing based on the input.

For example:

The database currently contains 100, 100, and 100 in a row of a table.
In the form there are 3 number boxes and the user inputs 3, 5, and 7.
The user hits submit and now the database contains 103, 105, and 107.
If they hit submit again, the database will contain 106, 110, and 114 (basically a multiplier effect). I do NOT want this to occur. How can I write a query so that the database changes relative to how much the input changes? Like if user changes inputs to 2, 4, and 6, the database will now read 102, 104, and 106?

The code is too long to post here so I'm basically just asking for ideas. Thanks!

**Edit:** Maybe one idea would be to generate a row of 100, 100, 100 every time? Use an auto increment so every time the form is submitted the latest row will reflect the current input?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If your calculations are handled on the frontend, why do you need to recalculate on the backend?

Comment: The calculations use data from the backend, which is updated by user input on the frontend...if that makes sense? When the user types input it doesn't change the backend data until they hit submit...but they can see the "what if" results in realtime. My problem is after they hit submit and the backend data changes, the retained input is not only affecting the realtime calculations (again, which retrieves backend data), but also the backend--because it is added every time they update.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have a single or multi user system. I suppose it is multi user since you have these problems.
The easiest way to prevent this is to clearly identify the user and the values he entered. And then do not change the basic values in the db, but save the values that each user submitted.
You should make a table just for user values and update them every time.
Just make a query adding each user value to your base value. Done.
You can store the initial values in a db, too. But you could also hard code them, depending on what you intend to do.

Comment: Yes it is multi-user. I got as far as making a table for each user's latest values but then I got mixed up on the data retrieval for cumulative inputted values. I probably just need to do some additional planning. Thanks for your comments.